# Kernel and nullity of a linear transformation.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $f(u)=\frac{du}{dx}$ be a linear transformation $f:V\rightarrow V$ where $V$ is the space of polynomials of order 3 or less over $\mathbb{R}$. What is the kernel of $f$? What is the nullity of $f$?

I know that $ker(f)=\{u\in V : f(u)=\frac{du}{dx}=0\}$ and the nullity of $f$ is the dimension of $ker(f)$. But how do I find the dimension of $ker(f)$? Is it $0$?

Comment: Think about constant functions. Will they belong to the kernel?

Answer (score 3):

So $\ker(f)$ is the set of all degree $\le 3$ polynomials over $\mathbb{R}$ such that their derivative is $0$. What are such polynomials? Once you know this, the dimension should be easy to compute (hint: $1 \in \mathbb{R}$).

Comment: I know they are zero-degree polynomials (constant functions). So is the dimension 1?

Comment: Yes, and why is that?

Comment: Because ker(f) is the set of real numbers.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

What family of functions always map to $0$ when taken the derivative of?
Functions degrees decrease at least 1 when taken the derivative of for polynomials, what does that tell you about the other functions?